# How to process this binary in the most optimized way in Java

Tags: java, optimization, arrays

I would like to know how I can optimize the following in java. I would like it on an Android phone so the less that gets put into memory the better.

I get a record-set that comprises of one column, this column holds binary data in a byte array. This is something I have never played with.

The structure of information in the binary data can be found here: [BLOB](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html)

I want to skip over SRID and MBRs, but I would like the ENDIAN, CLASS TYPE, AND the actual geometry data.

The actual processing of the geometry data is not so important in this question, more the how do I get the data and how do I get it fast.

```
Stmt stmt = local_db.prepare("Select geometry From Parcel");
while (stmt.step()){
    //stmt.column_bytes(0) holds the byte array
    //this could be used with a ByteArrayInputStream or perhaps a ByteBuffer
    //maybe something else, what ever would be faster??
    //
    //Next would be the proccessing of the byte array to get the values out.
    //Switch (ENDIAN){
    //  case 0 :
    //    
    //  break;
    //  default:
    //     
    //}
}
stmt.close();
```

In the end these shapes are going to be put straight to the renderer so I don't need to keep anything in memory. That's getting ahead of myself, but may be of use to you to see how I am going to use it in the end.

Comment: I suspect no matter what you do it will not be as slow as using a data base, so I would just make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry but not sure I get what you mean?? Are you saying it is always going to be slow as it is using a database? The query above gives back 17000 recs and cycles through them with no processing in about 260ms, which is fine. When it comes to processing the byte array, then it can turn into seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to predict what the "the fastest possible way" is going to be.  However, that probably shouldn't be your primary criteria for success.

What you actually need is an *application* that runs *fast enough*.  And in this context, the application performance includes the time taken to perform database queries, and fetch the results into the Java heap.  (Or read it from a file ...)

So I'd recommend the following approach:

1. Write it simply.
2. Write unit tests.
3. Test it thoroughly using the unit tests and correct any bugs.
4. Create a benchmark / sample data that you can use to measure how fast the code is currently.
5. Run the benchmark on the code.
6. Is it fast enough?  If YES, then stop.
7. Profile the code to determine where the bottlenecks are:

   - If the bottlenecks are in the database, work on optimizing the database schema and queries ...
   - If the bottlenecks are in the Java side, work on optimizing that.
8. Goto step 3 ... and see if your "optimization" helped.

In general, it is only worth optimizing areas of your code / implementation that are bottlenecks.  While there are exceptions (i.e. really gifted programmers), most developers don't have a particularly accurate intuition of where the real bottlenecks are.  And if you don't *know* that a particular area of code is a bottleneck, there is a *risk* that effort spent in optimizing it will be a waste of time.

Comment: Ok understood all that. I guess the first issue then is to start processing the data, don't suppose you know how to I can make a start on this as per criteria above?

Comment: @Hank - If really you understood what I was saying, then you would realise that the answer is "No".

Comment: the concepts are fine. I should have worded it better. I was talking about how to read the data out of the byte array as per the internal BLOB specs.

Comment: As I said.  And I will say it again.  Write it simply.  The chances are that the difference between "simple" and "optimal" won't make much of a difference OVERALL.  Because the chances are that the byte-level processing is NOT the bottleneck.

Comment: You have only answered half the question but I do appreciate your time.